# Which HTTP method should Login and Logout Actions use in a "RESTful" setup

Tags: rest

Curious how others here would represent these in a REST architecture.

```
/users/login/
/users/logout/
```

These endpoints set up the session to login in the user, or clear it, respectively. My gut says POST, but I'm not in fact creating an object.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2001773/165674

Comment: For logout, it is discussed in length at http://stackoverflow.com/q/3521290/873282 (with the same result)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logout: GET or POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521290/logout-get-or-post)

Comment: POST doesn't have to create a new resource. It just sends data to the server. What the server does with this data is up to the server.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You should use `POST` - using `GET` for these actions can lead to issues with browser prefetching and search engine spidering. See ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14587231/51), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7140074/51))

Comment: Concise, it was not necessary to make a research on it. Thanks

Comment: Yes, `POST` sounds like the most rational option for a logout request and is what I would consider by default, however, doesn't `POST` mean "create"? What form-data would you be sending for a logout request with `POST`? A `DELETE` request would hardly be suitable either unless you have something like `DELETE /session/{id}`. `PUT` would mean we're replacing something, so that's out of the question. What are your thoughts on `PATCH`?

Answer (score -5):

maybe CONNECT? MDN says:

> The HTTP CONNECT method starts two-way communications with the requested resource. It can be used to open a tunnel.

as login means maintaining a session between browser and server, CONNECT method makes the most sense.