# Django Redirect the Logout Process to a View

Tags: django, django-login

I am very new to django, I have a following template:

```
{% if settings.LOGIN_SYSTEM %}
     <a href="{{ settings.LOGOUT_URL }}?target={{ settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL}}">{% trans %}sign out{% endtrans %}</a>
{% endif %}
```

I also have a view that clears out all the session:

```
class LogoutView(TemplateView):

    redirect_field_name = "target"

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

I want to make sure the login signal goes through the LogoutView get method. Can I call a view method from template?

If so an example would be great.

Answer (score 1):

To logout use POST instead of GET. It is a [architecture issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521290/logout-get-or-post).
So to logout you should make a post request like the following example.

Logout template form

```
<form action="{% url 'logout' %}" method="post" >
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
</form>
```

Logout url

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    # other urls...
)
```

Logout view

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

class LogoutView(ProcessFormView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logout(request)
        return redirect('login-url-name')
```

Answer (score 0):

Example logout

```
@require_POST
def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```