# How to disable intermediate signout page in Django allauth

Tags: django, django-views, django-allauth

How to disable the intermediate signout page from django allauth. When the user clicks on the signout link on my site I want him to logout right away, I want to remove this intermediate page
[image: Screenshot of signout intermediate page]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Set `ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET` to `True` in your settings.

Also see [the documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#logout)

Comment: This shouldn't be done over `GET`, because anybody can `<img src="https://example.com/account/logout">` and get you signed out without you ever knowing it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521290/logout-get-or-post

Comment: What's wrong with being unknowingly logged out? If anything, that should be a feature, not a bug =)

Comment: Answers by Kalob and Adam are more useful. Even allauth doc says- "GET is not designed to modify the server state, and in this case it can be dangerous." It's pretty easy to do it with a post.

Answer (score 11):

Using a GET request is probably a bad idea due to browsers prefetching urls from the URL bar. Chrome (as of right now) is pretty bad for this; it'll send a `GET` request to pages it think you'll hit `enter` on when typing in your URL bar.

Plus, people can add a link such as `<img src="https://example.com/account/logout/">` and you'll be logged out. That's not a security risk since it's logging you out, but it is certainly annoying for your users.

Instead, you should consider using a `POST` request using a form with CSRF. Django Allauth already comes with this. Here's the `<form>` from the intermediate signout page:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'account_logout' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}"/>
  {% endif %}
  <button class="STYLE_ME" type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>
```

In my case, I just added this to the site header and made the submit `<button>` look like every other link using CSS so it feels the same to them, but the form will use a POST request.

But if that's not a solution you can implement for any reason, open your `settings.py` file (or your main settings file) and set:

```
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
```

^ The above setting will do what you need. For further Django Allauth settings, check out their [configuration page](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html?highlight=ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET).

Answer (score 3):

Here's another shortcut for preserving the POST request, if you don't want to mess with styling the form button with something like this:

Hide the form:

```
<form style='display: none;' method="post" action="{% url 'account_logout' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/redirect_target/"/>
  <button id="signOutBtn" type="submit">Logout</button>
</form>
```

Submit with a click event attached to whatever element you've already styled:

```
$(document).on('click', '#signOutLink', function() {
    $('#signOutBtn').click()
});
```