# Formatting a list item in jQuery Mobile for a POST link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I have a question about jQuery Mobile formatting, and how to get an `<li>` to format properly in a listview.  The MVC 4 default template for a Mobile application in Visual Studio has a logoff link that uses a GET call to logoff.  Here is the markup:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Change password", "ChangePassword")</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log off", "LogOff")</li>
</ul>
```

And here is the call:

```
// GET: /Account/LogOff
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

With jQuery Mobile, it looks like this:

[image]

In contrast, the MVC 4 default template for an internet application uses a POST method for the same logoff:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = 
"logoutForm" })) {@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<a ref="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>}
```

What I would like to do is to use a POST method in my Mobile application to log off instead of the default GET method (in keeping with best practice: [Logout: GET or POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521290/logout-get-or-post)).  I can get the link to work properly, but what I am having trouble with is getting the button to look the way it did when it was using the GET method.

My markup looks like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Change password", "ChangePassword")</li>
<li>@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
{@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>}
   </li>
</ul>
```

But the result looks like this:

[image]

I’ve tried putting the `<li>` tags around the `<a>` tag instead, but the results are not any better:

[image]

Could someone explain why this `<li>` tag is being formatted differently than the one above it, and how I might get it to look like the one at the top of this post?

Comment: try to put the form inside a div!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you feel like creating your own custom CSS in that list item don't put the actual `<form>` inside of it because forms have their own default CSS. Instead keep the form somewhere outside the list item and put the button itself inside the list item

```
   <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Change password", "ChangePassword")</li>
    <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
   </ul>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" }))
    {
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    }
```

Comment: That worked!  Thanks, that was exactly the insight I was looking for.  Glad I didn't have to create custom CSS.

Comment: wow....so easy.  Thanks!   Hey, is this your site?    http://www.khalidabuhakmeh.com/wtf-asp-net-mvc-5-sample