# Span with a href link not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, href, html

Working to put a href in a span class, but I cant get the href link to work.

```
<a href="../../public/bassengweb/logout">Logg ut<span class="label label-danger"></span></a>
```

Also the label-danger wont show up.

Comment: shouldn't it be the other way round (anchor embedded in the span) if you wish the class to cover the `a` element ? why don't you assign the class to `a` ? what do you mena by "does't show up" ?

Comment: You [don't want to use a GET for logging out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14587231/6083675).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Link to working span - Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/128879)

That's because of this line in the CSS:

```
.label:empty{
  display:none;
}
```

If you write something between the `span` tags, it will work.

```
<a href="../../public/bassengweb/logout"><span class="label label-danger">Logg ut</span></a>
```

Although, it will look terrible with 'normal' bootstrap label when hovered, maybe do something like this:

```
<a href="../../public/bassengweb/logout">Logg ut</a><span class="label label-danger">Danger</span>
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the best way! It works easy and clean.

```html
<span onclick="window.location.href='www.google.com';">text</span>
```

and then you can give it a `class:hover` for the color

Comment: This is [terrible for accessibility](https://karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans). It cannot be accessed with a keyboard, and prevents  many other interactions such as right click, shift+click, drag+drop.

Answer (score 1):

The `<span>` with class `label` should have content, 
check the Boostrap's example [Boostrap Component - Label](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#labels)
Maybe you should try to put an "x"

```
<a href="../../public/bassengweb/logout">Logg ut<span class="label label-danger">x</span></a>
```

or use glyphicons, maybe

```
<a href="../../public/bassengweb/logout">Logg ut<span class="label label-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For label css use:

```
class="label label-important"
```

it worked for me