# Log out button not working in mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an MVC application with different user accounts and passwords. The log in feature works fine, but when I click the log out button I get a 404 error saying:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had >its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled >correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Account/LogOff

This is the code for the log out button:

```
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account")</li>
                
            </ul>
        </div>
```

This is the code in the AccountController

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        Session.Clear();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: I believe it's the HttpPost attribute. Have you tried removing that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Html.ActionLink` renders a regular hyperlink, which causes a GET request.

Your `LogOff` has the `HttpPost` attribute, which means it'll only answer to POST requests. Remove the attribute and your action will work. The `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` is also not needed, it is for forms.

---

Note: I no longer stand by my original answer. Although it fixes the problem at hand, logging out should really be a POST instead, due to [browser prefetching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14587231/247702) and [potential malicious behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3522013/247702). So instead of using a hyperlink, there should be a form with a submit button styled as a hyperlink.

Comment: the update you posted is good information to know.

Answer (score 4):

Just adding to answer given by @Stijn: `ActionLink` sends a **get** request to the server and your `LogOff` Action is expecting a **post** request which contains **AntiForgeryToken**

You need to create a form, with a submit button like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
 {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     <input type="submit" value="Logout" class="btn btn-primary"/>
 }
```

This would hit your `LogOff` Action, in Account Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(
        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I handled it by creating a hidden form, then on click of the Log Out link, it submits the form. Like this

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("LogOff", "Account")" id="signoutfrm" style="display:none;">
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</form>

<a href="" onclick="$('#signoutfrm').submit(); return false;">LOGOUT</a>
```

It worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

As per Microsoft MVC project template,

```
// Note: Action Name, Controller Name
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul>            
    <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

- Since logoff require `AntiForgeryToken` it is not allowed in get method. You have to use POST method.
- `RedirectToAction` cannot be used for post method.