# Bootstrap logout link

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap in my application. After adding some design I started adding some functionality. I have a navbar with a dropdown, like [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-static-top/). On my Website, this also features a logout link:

```
<li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
```

But my problem is, that my logout will only accept POST requests. 
So my simple question is: How can I make this a POST request instead of GET?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Why does it only accept `POST`?, this doesn't really make sense. 
2. you need to use a form to send `POST-requests` or you can use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit with an onclick

Comment: POST is [recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3521290/167781) action for the logout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is two ways to get it solved:

1. Change your PHP side so it accepts `$_GET` request. (Tip: Use `$_REQUEST` to get value from `$_GET` or `$_POST`.
2. Use jQuery/js for that (sorry, no js example).

```
    <a href="/logout" id="logout">Logout</a>

    // load jQuery first.
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#logout").click(function(){
          $.post($(this).attr("href"), function(){
              window.location = "www.example.com/login"; // or any other page after logging out.
          });
       });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me :) I'm new with PHP/HTML/JS/jQuery... I think I need to take a closer look at JS/jQuery. THANKS! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
<li><a href="/logout">Logout</a><form method="post" action="logout.php"><!--Whatever must be in your form--></form></li>
```

and

```
$("a + form").click(function(){
    $(this).next('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want POST request then you should use form

Example:

```
<form method='post' action='logout.php'>
    <input type='submit' value='Logout'>
    </form>
```

Comment: It works, but I will have a button in my dropdown, which I don't want ;)

Comment: You could style it to look like a link or whatever you want.