# Styling dropdown-menu item that has to call a POST action

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, http-post

My ASP.NET MVC5 application uses a Twitter Bootstrap `navbar` at the top. One item in the navigation bar is a `dropdown-menu` for logged in users. Inside the dropdown is an `ActionLink` to the profile page, and another item to Log Off.

The Log Off action is following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14587231/419956) thus calling a `HttpPost` action, meaning it can't use a plain `ActionLink`. Instead I use a `BeginForm` and a `input` of `type=submit`. The Razor view looks like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dopdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
            John Doe <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Account", "Index", "Account")
            </li>
            <li>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Logout", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                  <input type="submit" value="LogOff" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"/>
                }
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

However, this renders like so:

[image: rendered dropdown-menu]

I've tried replacing the `<input type="submit" />` with this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit(); return false;">LogOff</a>
```

However, the `form` element that wraps this `a` tag breaks Bootstrap styling as well, rendering like this:

[image: rendered dropdown-menu after changing code]

**What's the proper way to handle this?**

I'm asking this the way I did above, because I'd prefer a solution that keeps my Razor view at least as simple as it is now, but preferably even make it simpler. Perhaps there's a `Html` helper method I've overlooked that could do what I need in a way that the rendered markup is picked up by Bootstrap?

---

As a footnote, here's a [html](/questions/tagged/html)+[css](/questions/tagged/css) repro to fiddle with.

**Warning:** the width of Stack Overflow snippets tends to trigger Bootstrap's responsiveness features, which may alter the view slightly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown"> 
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    John Doe
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <form action="xyz" method="POST">
                            <input type="submit" value="LogOff" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" />
                        </form>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Should be just a matter of styling the `<input type="submit" />` element - something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2gkh6d8/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing something similar to @Repo's answer, yet different enough to warrant posting it as a different solution. The basic idea is the same, this answer also uses the workaround I mentioned in my question: using javascript on an anchor tag to submit the form.

With this *workaround* the form is very close to the anchor tag, making the code a bit easier to read in the future, also preventing the need to use a `byId` selector:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dopdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
            John Doe <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Account", "Index", "Account")
            </li>
            <li>
                @* WORKAROUND: Anchor tag outside the form element to make Bootstrap style it properly. *@
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Logout", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
                { }
                <a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().find('form').submit(); return false;">LogOff</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I do consider this an ugly workaround though, so invite anyone to include a more proper solution that doesn't require this type of hard to understand markup or a bunch of custom css rules...

Answer (score 2):

Place your form in a div with display: none; and use an anchor to click the submit button =)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dopdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
            John Doe <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                @Html.ActionLink("Account", "Index", "Account")
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" onclick="$('#mySubmit').click();">Log Off</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div style="display: none;">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Logout", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input id="mySubmit" type="submit" value="LogOff" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn"/>
    }
</div>
```