# Why does Laravel, by default, logout via POST (As opposed to GET)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Within the context of a Laravel application, what is the significance of POSTing to perform a logout? Is there some security and/or session particularity that POSTing over just GETing?

The relevant portion from the generated `make::auth`:

```xml
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li>
    <a
      href="{{ url('/logout') }}"
      onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
      Logout
    </a>

    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
    </form>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is a matter of choice, but also has been [discussed before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521290/logout-get-or-post) on Stackoverflow.

Comment: In general any action which would change the server's state should be sent via POST. That's what the suggestion has always been.

Comment: RE: "Marked as duplicate" - When posted, I was asking in the context of laravel (I thought it was a particular feature of laravel), but can see how the broader "original" question can also apply

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GET requests are supposed to be "[safe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4)" and shouldn't have any significant side effects. It shouldn't matter, for example, if a precaching feature of a browser followed the link. That should just get some data.

Logging the user out would be a significant side effect, so GET would be inappropriate.