# How can we make a logout page in SpringMVC without using Spring Security?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, session

I am newbie in SpringMVC, trying to make a logout page in an employee details application.  An employee can login into his/her details and can change it. But i am confused how to set the logout page.
Please tell me the possible alternatives through which a logout page can make without using spring-security.

thanks

Comment: Use Spring Security auth

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb I want to achieve the result without using spring security

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply provide a link with url of logout controller method. Suppose you have controller named MiscController with method logout for handling logout, Then code would look like..

```
@Controller
public class MiscController {

    @RequestMapping("/logout")
    public String logout(HttpServletRequest request){
        request.getSession().invalidate();
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Now in your jsp page you can have a link like..

`<a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/logout">Logout</a>`

On Clicking the logout, You will be logged out and redirected to index.jsp page[Assuming ViewResolver is configured correctly].

Comment: do we need to set the session in the login page ... from where we are calling this   request.getSession().invalidate() in logout method

Comment: When you login, you set user details is Session Object. So, when you logout, you need to invalidate all data saved in session object.

Comment: Each and every request [HttpServletRequest] object has HttpSession object associated with it where you save data related to a particular session. For details, You should read attribute scopes topic in java Servlet .

Comment: Also, it's better to use `POST` method for logout handler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521290/logout-get-or-post