# How can i redirect to login if user tries logout route directly

Tags: php, laravel, php-7.2, laravel-6.2

Everything in this login is working fine but if a user tries logout route directly

**localhost:8000/logout**
it shows the following error

[image]

i want a way so that i can redirect to login if the route is called directly,
what could be the vest way for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a route like this in your routes file. It is because only post method exist for logout.

```
Route::get('logout', function() {
   return redirect()->route('login');
});
```

Comment: Without `Auth::Logout()` the user will again redirected to the "Home Page".

Answer (score 0):

> **A word of caution:** As Laurel mentioned in this comments, using `GET` request for `Logout` is a bad idea,
> *Read [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14587231/4050077) on StackOverflow before proceeding.*

*Where is the problem?*

#### The error message is self explanatory.

> The `logout` route doesn't support HTTP Method `GET`, but `POST`.

*What is the solution?*

You can define a `GET` route for `logout`, if you really wants to do it.

```
Route::get('logout', function() {
   // Do whatever you want to do with Logout
  Auth::logout(); // logout the user
  return redirect()->route('login'); // redirect the user to login page
});
```

Comment: This is a bad idea as having a GET method for logout will allow any random website to silently log you and your users out (by setting an image’s source to the logout GET URL for example). In fact this is why Laravel changed logout to be a POST (as older versions used GET).

Comment: Yeah! You're right. But the author of this question, wants to do it with a GET request. 
Anyway, I will update my answer with this note. Thanks for the information @Laurel

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('check_logout','ExampleController@check_logout');
Route::get('logout',function(){
    return redirect('login');
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This can be a solution, but could you please add an explanation about the code provided?