# OnPost not called when trying to log out

Tags: post, blazor, logout

I have a Blazor app where I sucessfully log out with a GET request.

https://localhost:44300/Identity/Account/LogOut

```
public class LogoutModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
        return Redirect("/Identity/Account/Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

However [with good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14587231/283787) this GET should be a POST.
So I changed the code to:

```
public class LogoutModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
        return Redirect("/Identity/Account/Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

The `OnPostAsync()` method is not invoked and I get an 400 response when I call the following fetch method.

```
await fetch('https://localhost:44300/Identity/Account/LogOut', { method: 'POST', headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }})
```

What do I need to do to ensure it get's called?

Comment: What do you expect to trigger this? Are you doing any POST request somewhere?

Comment: Details added @T.Trassoudaine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request verification was failing, so I disabled it by adding the [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.ignoreantiforgerytokenattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to the LogoutModel class:

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)]
public class LogoutModel : PageModel
{
}
```